# Mvc doesn't render nested master page in Umbraco

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, umbraco

I have a master template that calls "RenderBody()" and a "OneIn" template that is a child under the Master page. I also call the RenderBody() function in the OneIn template but then it gives me this error:

```
The file "~/Views/OneIn.cshtml" cannot be requested directly because it calls the "RenderSection" method.
```

The "RenderSection" was i actually "renderbody" i was just trying something new, and it didn't work either

Nest Path:

```
Master

  -> Homepage

  -> OneIn 

    -> One Column Page
```

I also have these lines on code on top of all pages:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
Layout = "ParentPageName.cshtml";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have an action method that is trying to return the "onein" layout directly, which can't happen if you are calling `RenderSection` or `RenderBody` inside of it. Thank of any View that has RenderSection/Body in it as an `abstract` class that can't be new-ed up but instead have to be inherited!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I found this as well which is a bit jarring when coming from Master Templates.  You can have many levels of template inheritance, but your content pages can only use templates that are at the lowest level.  That would be One Column Page in your example.